# What was Han searching through when he found where Lando was?

Tags: star-wars, technology, the-empire-strikes-back, millennium-falcon

In *The Empire Strikes Back* we have [this exchange](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html) between Han and Leia

> HAN: Then we've got to find a safe port somewhere around here. Got any ideas?
>
> LEIA: No.  Where are we?
>
> HAN: The Anoat system.
>
> LEIA: Anoat system. There's not much there.
>
> HAN: No. Well, wait. This is interesting. Lando.
>
> He points to a computer mapscreen on the control panel.  Leia slips out 
>   of her chair and moves next to the handsome pilot.  Small light points 
>   representing several systems flash by on the computer screen.
>
> LEIA: Lando system?
>
> HAN: Lando's not a system, he's a man. Lando Calrissian.  He's a card  player, gambler, scoundrel.  You'd like him.
>
> LEIA: Thanks.
>
> HAN: Bespin. It's pretty far, but I think we can make it.

What exactly was he using to search, that had such detailed information about Lando, and where to find him?

Comment: Just using some real-life knowledge, most ships have a list of ports where they can load/unload their goods. I might assume that the Millennium Falcon has a similar system for searching for space ports within a refined distance.

Comment: I don't think the device had detailed information about Lando, Han just saw Bespin and knew Lando now controlled/owned it. However, that doesn't exactly answer the question of ___what___ he was searching through so I'll leave it as a comment.

Comment: Like @TheLethalCarrot, I never understood Han's computer as including any information about Lando other than -- possibly -- that Lando was the administrator of Cloud City in the Bespin system. The information about Lando being a card player, etc., was Han's personal knowledge.

Comment: Space Google, of course!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**His ship's logs.**

> “Funny,” Han said after thinking for a moment, “I have the feeling I’ve been in this area before. **Let me check my logs.”**
>   “You keep logs?” Leia was more impressed by the minute. “My, how organized,” she teased.
>   “Well, sometimes,” he answered as he hunted through the computer readout. “Ah-ha, I knew it! Lando—now this should be interesting.”
>   “I never heard of that system,” said Leia.
>
> <sub><sup>[Empire Strikes Back: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_(novel))</sup></sub>

Note that since this doesn't exactly agree with the dialogue from the film, it's considered Legends.

---

The new junior novelisation simply refers to it as **a map.**

> Han leans forward. “Then we’ve got to find a safe port around here to complete repairs. Any ideas?”
>   Chewbacca brings up **an electronic map** on the ship’s main control panel. The small crew pores over it. Han groans. “Anoat system. Nothing around here but mining colonies and…” He pauses. He is suddenly interested. “And Lando.”
>
> <sub><sup>[The Empire Strikes Back: So You Want To Be A Jedi?](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back:_So_You_Want_to_Be_a_Jedi%3F)</sup></sub>

The older junior novelisation concurs. **A mapscreen (with a map).**

> “Then we’ve got to find a safe port somewhere around here.” **Han activated a mapscreen on his control panel**, and Leia leaned closer to him to study the map. Han asked, “Got any ideas?”
>   “No. Where are we?”
>   “The Anoat system.”
>
> <sub><sup>[The Empire Strikes Back - Official Junior Novelization](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

This mirrors the note in the junior Storybook. **A map of the local systems.**

> “Then we have to find a safe port around here.” He looked at a map on his computer screen. “Funny. I have the feeling I've been in this area before. Let me check.” He focused an image on the screen. “I knew it. Lando! This should be interesting.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Empire Strikes Back Storybook](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back_Storybook)</sup></sub>

Comment: I thought all official movie novelisations were considered canon, or has that changed?

Comment: @MrLister -The newest one is considered fully canon. The older ones are Legends *where they conflict with what we are in the films or invent New scenes and dialogue*